# How to manage development dependencies in Conda?

Tags: conda, continuous-deployment, packaging

I would like to have two environments: a production environment that is a strict *subset* of a testing environment. How can I achieve this using Conda (or micromamba)?

Testing requires some extra utilities that don't need to be bundled in the production docker image. The main idea is to ensure that the sub-dependencies in the production install are the exact *same versions* as were tested in the companion environment.

Example possibilities:

- Is there an option to specify a constraints file (like for pip) that can include more packages than are currently being installed (and a way to populate this file from the test env, to use when creating the prod env)?
- Is there some way to limit conda to only retrieving packages from a local cache that was freshly populated by the install of a previous env?
- Is there an option to install the additional (testing) requirements while forcing conda not to upgrade/downgrade any existing packages in the environment? (But basing the test env from a duplicate of the prod env in this manner may make it impossible to satisfy version conflicts..)

Answer (score 2):

Conda doesn't directly support *nesting* environments in any useful way. However, there are well-defined steps that will yield environments with identical versions of common packages. Below is one possible procedure.

### Clone + Frozen Install

To give a concrete example, and one that uses Conda in its generality (which is not Python-centric), let's consider a development project for **an R package**. Suppose we have the two sets of requirements:

**requirements.prod.txt**

```bash
r-base=4.0
r-magrittr
r-dplyr
```

**requirements.test.txt**

```bash
r-testthat
r-usethis
```

The following commands would create two environments, where the testing one (**pkg_test**) would be a superset of the production (**pkg_prod**) one:

```bash
## first, use Mamba if you aren't already
## conda install -n base conda-forge::mamba

## create the dev environment
mamba create -n pkg_prod --file requirements.prod.txt

## create the test environment as a clone
mamba create --clone pkg_prod -n pkg_test

## install the additional requirements, without updating pkgs
mamba install -n pkg_test --freeze-installed --file requirements.test.txt
```

If you change requirements, best would be to recreate the environments. I recommend Mamba because it minimizes solve time, provides more precise diagnoses when things go wrong, and rarely gives a surprising solve result.

Comment: One issue of approaching in the prod→test direction (clone and freeze-installed) is that a testing tool might require an older version of a subdependency than already installed for the prod env, breaking/preventing the test install. Is there also a well defined procedure for approaching in the test→prod direction instead?

Answer (score 2):

Going in the opposite direction (test -> prod) to [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69559303/570918) is a bit more tricky. Basically, we want to solve for the test environment first, and then only use package versions from that environment to create the production one. Below is one approach I checked will work, though it's not standard.

### Temporary Package Cache + Offline Solve

The main idea is to use a temporary package cache so that only packages installed in the test environment would be available to the solve step when creating the **pkg_prod** environment. Here we go:

```bash
## create a temporary directory for package cache
tmp_pkg_cache=$(mktemp -d)

## create test environment (it uses both prod and test reqs)
CONDA_PKGS_DIRS=${tmp_pkg_cache} mamba create -n pkg_test \
  --file requirements.prod.txt --file requirements.test.txt

## restrict prod env creation to packages in the tmp cache
CONDA_PKGS_DIRS=${tmp_pkg_cache} mamba create -n pkg_prod \
  --file requirements.prod.txt --offline

## clean up cache
rm -rf ${tmp_pkg_cache}
```

Again, if requirements change, I'd remove the environments and rerun these steps. Note that this approach ignores existing package caches, so it will download every package - though if the runner is part of CI, that's probably the case anyway.

Comment: How would the outcome (of `--offline` with primed cache) differ compared to `create --clone` && `uninstall --prune`? (I guess the latter would enable using a cache, but would the uninstall be expected to leave additional clutter in the env, or to break if there was also a PyPI dependency?)

Comment: @benjimin theoretically it should work, but the last few times I’ve reached for `--prune` it didn’t work - neither the Conda nor the Mamba implementation. Though, I thought I saw the Mamba repo working on it recently (last couple weeks).

Comment: The packages directory configuration is [documented here](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/configuration/use-condarc.html#specify-pkg-directories).